# Executing a gant script from a grails project

Tags: grails, groovy, gant

I have written my own gant script which works fine from the command line. Now I need to run this script from a grails project like this:

```
def outputMessage

try{

    GroovyScriptEngine engine = new GroovyScriptEngine("/www", this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    engine.run("scripts/MyOwnScript_.groovy", "param1 param2")
    outputMessage = "<br> OK: Script run successfully"
}
catch (Exception e) {
    outputMessage += "<br> ERROR: There has been running the script"
}
```

The error I am getting is "No such property: includeTargets for class: MyOwnScript_", as my gant script requires some other scripts.

Does anybody know a proper way to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The main problem was that I need to run the grails using the full path like this:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv()
final processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder()
processBuilder.directory(new File("folderFromWhereIWantToRunTheGantScript"))
processBuilder.command([env['GRAILS_HOME']+"/bin/grails","MyOwnScript param1 param2"])
println processBuilder.directory()
Process proc = processBuilder.start()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)

proc.waitFor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get path to your script folder and execute an external process like

```
["groovy", "scripts/MyOwnScript_.groovy", "param1", "param2"].execute()
```

See [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management) for more info about running external process in groovy